# Automate github-copilot in Visual-studio-code

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I am trying o automate the use of copilot in my code
Apparently only after I put the comment pattern and hit enter key, the codepilot generates output
So I tried coding \r\n and \n in my program after code comments pattern for CodePilot. It doesnt seem to work.

Is there any other way I can automate copilot runs in my code?

SO I tried parsing my code and where ever I had doubts about the code, I put in a CodePilot comment pattern and added a "\n" and "\r\n". I expected that when I load the file in VS studio code (Which has a copilot account configured) the copilot will run automatically and generate the code

I am open to suggestions as to how I can automate copilot. If there is an alternate way any tips will be appreciated